# Как правильно умножить число на десять и прибавить другое число?

Tags: c++

Когда я записываю цифру в переменную, цифра храниться до того момента, покуда я другое значение не запишу, а мне нужно сделать, чтоб старое значение осталось, тип сместилось в старший разряд, а новое значение записалось в младший....... пример: у меня есть цифра 1 в переменной, и когда я заношу туда цифру 2, то нужно чтоб было 12 ?

Comment: Здесь нет битов...

Comment: Как вы получаете из, скажем, 34 число 345? Это 34*10+5. А из 15 - 157? Это 15*10+7. Ну, вот и думайте... Учтите только знак для знаковых чисел, если будете передавать 5, а не -5...

Comment: Почитайте книгу **Булевая алгебра** Питера Буля, изучите операторы `&`,`|`,`&&`,`||`,`<<`,`>>`

Answer (score 4):

это не побитовые операции. Но вот Вам код

```
int shift(int num, int digit)
{
    return num*10 + digit;
}
```

пользоваться так

```
int x = 1;
x = shift(x, 2);
cout << x;
```

можно конечно переписать и так

```
void shift(int &num, int digit)
{
    num num*10 + digit;
}
```

и пользоваться так

```
int x = 1;
shift(x, 2);
cout << x;
```

но это на любителя.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и вот так сделать, только мне очень интересно зачем?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class someclass{
private:
  int a;
public:
  someclass():a(0)
  {}
  void operator =(int b){
  a=a*10+b;
  }
  void show_a(){
      cout<<a;
  }

};
int main(){
  someclass c;
  c=5;
  c=3;
  c.show_a();
  return 0;
}
```